# "Sunday last week" strtotime() error on Sundays

Tags: php, mysql

To keep my kids happy, I've been implementing the [Yellow Car Game](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Yellow%20Car%20Game) in PHP for long car journeys. One of them sits on my phone and adds yellow cars as and when they see them. Counters should increment each of their scores, with the score resetting every Sunday night and displaying last week's winner.

This was incrementing correctly last week, and is again this week, but I noticed on Sunday that all scores were sitting at 0, and my score for last week is not totalling at all.

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $un = "username";
    $pw = "password";
    $db = "database";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $un, $pw, $db);

    $thisweek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Monday this week'));
    //echo $thisweek;
    $lastweek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Monday last week'));
    //echo $lastweek;

    $mquery = "SELECT COUNT(who) AS total FROM records WHERE (who = 'Matthew') AND (nowdate >= '$thisweek')";
    $mresult = mysqli_query($con, $mquery);
    $mdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mresult);
    $mcount = $mdata['total'];

    $rquery = "SELECT COUNT(who) AS total FROM records WHERE (who = 'Roisin') AND (nowdate >= '$thisweek')";
    $rresult = mysqli_query($con, $rquery);
    $rdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult);
    $rcount = $rdata['total'];

    $mlquery = "SELECT COUNT(who) AS total FROM records WHERE (who = 'Matthew') AND (nowdate >= '$lastweek') AND (nowdate < $thisweek)";
    $mlresult = mysqli_query($con, $mlquery);
    $mldata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mlresult);
    $mlcount = $mldata['total'];

    $rlquery = "SELECT COUNT(who) AS total FROM records WHERE (who = 'Roisin') AND (nowdate >= '$lastweek') AND (nowdate < $thisweek)";
    $rlresult = mysqli_query($con, $rlquery);
    $rldata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rlresult);
    $rlcount = $rldata['total'];

    if ($mlcount > $rlcount) {
        $lcount = "Matthew";
        $first = $mlcount;
        $second = $rlcount;
    }
    else {
        $lcount = "Roisin";
        $first = $rlcount;
        $second = $mlcount;
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Yellow Car</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pure-g-r">
            <div class="pure-u-1 text-center">
                <h1>Yellow Car!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u-1-2 padded text-center">
                <form class="pure-form" method="post" action="matt-add.php">
                    <button type="submit" class="pure-button button-car pure-input-1">Matthew</button>
                </form>
                <p>
                    This Week: <strong class="blue-text"><?php echo $mcount; ?></strong>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-u-1-2 padded text-center">
                <form class="pure-form" method="post" action="rosh-add.php">
                    <button type="submit" class="pure-button button-car pure-input-1">Roisin</button>
                </form>
                <p>
                    This Week: <strong class="blue-text"><?php echo $rcount; ?></strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-g-r">
            <div class="pure-u-1 text-center">
                <h2>
                    <?php
                        if ($first == $second) {
                    ?>
                        Last week was a <span class="blue-text">draw</span>! (<?php echo $first . "-" . $second; ?>)
                    <?php
                        }
                        else {
                    ?>
                        Last week's winner was: <span class="blue-text"><?php echo $lcount; ?></span>! (<?php echo $first . "-" . $second; ?>)
                    <?
                        }
                    ?>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The database is simple for this; one table that logs the date and their name. Add query:

```
INSERT INTO records (who, nowdate) VALUES ('$who', NOW())
```

I tried echoing the date on Sunday 2nd January, but it told me this week was the 9th, and last week was the 2nd, which was exactly 7 days out.

If anyone can advise of any mistakes in my code, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I recall correctly relative date phrases have some interesting interpretations depending on how they're constructed. For instance, I believe `'Monday this week'` and `'this week Monday'` will give you two different dates. Also, the week rolls over on Sunday when using relative date strings, so that could explain part of your issue as well.

Comment: Yes, try testing with `Monday`, `last Monday`, `next Monday`.

Comment: I have tried with Monday also. Which echoing the date seems to be correct now, "this week" = `2014-02-03`, "last week" = `2014-01-27`, the counter showing last week's score is still sitting on 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to single quote your `$thisweek` in your two queries like below ...

```
 $mlquery = "SELECT COUNT(who) AS total FROM records WHERE (who = 'Matthew') AND (nowdate >= '$lastweek') AND (nowdate < '$thisweek')";
    $mlresult = mysqli_query($con, $mlquery);
    $mldata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mlresult);
    $mlcount = $mldata['total'];

    $rlquery = "SELECT COUNT(who) AS total FROM records WHERE (who = 'Roisin') AND (nowdate >= '$lastweek') AND (nowdate < '$thisweek')";
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Fingers crossed come next Monday my code will tick over correctly, now!